# Pine tree program spacing incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I'm creating a program to draw out a pine tree and the spacing is off and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Currently, the code goes like this:

```
def print_shifted_triangle(n, m, symbol):
    p1 = " "
    p2 = symbol
    number_of_asterisks = 1
    number_of_spaces = n-1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        triangle = p1*m + p1*number_of_spaces + p2*number_of_asterisks
        print(triangle)
        number_of_asterisks = number_of_asterisks+2
        number_of_spaces = number_of_spaces-1


def print_pine_tree(n, symbol):
    for i in range(2,n+2):
        print_shifted_triangle(i,0,symbol)

def main():
    symbol = input("Please enter a symbol: ")
    n = int(input("How many triangles? "))
    print_pine_tree(n, symbol)

main()
```

When I enter symbol as @ and n as 3, it prints this:

```
 @
@@@
  @
 @@@
@@@@@
   @
  @@@
 @@@@@
@@@@@@@
```

How do I align the  spacing so that it becomes like this?

```
   @
  @@@
   @
  @@@
 @@@@@
   @
  @@@
 @@@@@
@@@@@@@
```

Comment: Looks like you need more spaces in some places on a per-area basis.

Comment: Where on the code would I add the spacing?

Comment: Where you print the "branches"?

Comment: > triangle = p1*m + p1*[change this] + p2*number_of_asterisks   < this needs to be more complex.

Comment: But wouldn't that affect each line instead of each triangle?

Comment: I put p1*(spaces-n+4) but that would only print it correctly for when n goes up to 3

Comment: The number of spaces is directly related to the number of asterisks, right? Shouldn't the number of asterisks be incorporated into that formula?

Answer (score -1):

You should know last element length (or predict). Than You can use text.center(last_elem_length,' ') .

```
def print_pine(n, symbol):
    pine_list = [[x*symbol+symbol for x in range(n+y) if x % 2 == 0] for y in range(n)]
    max_len = len(pine_list[-1][-1])
    for pine in pine_list:
        for row in pine:
            print(row.center(max_len, ' '))

print_pine(5, '@')
```

Temporarily stored in list pine "rows" are printed at the end when we know length of the last element.

```
    @    
   @@@   
  @@@@@  
    @    
   @@@   
  @@@@@  
    @    
   @@@   
  @@@@@  
 @@@@@@@ 
    @    
   @@@   
  @@@@@  
 @@@@@@@ 
    @    
   @@@   
  @@@@@  
 @@@@@@@ 
@@@@@@@@@
```